# How to solve this Minesweeper game with deduction and without guessing?

Tags: minesweeper

In the Google game of Minesweeper, in all previous games, you could find with deduction. But in this game (picture of the game), it seems like you can only guess.
Is there a way to solve this with deduction? Could you explain how?

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you cropped out the number of mines remaining?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the yellow area, the middle 2 says you can only have 2 mines in that 3 tiles, and since the left 2 already has a mine (near the 3) you know that the left-most tiles can only contain 1 mine, therefore a mine must be on the right side. Giving that, you easily find the second mine. And completing that yellow area you can then complete the blue area (red 3), having the mine under the 4.

I can't help you more than this :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense, now. Actually, what I thought was that there was two solutions, but it was actually only one solution so that the left "two", didn't have three flags.

Comment: @mario no worries! Feel free to mark as accepted one of the answers by clicking the green tick :)

Answer (score 0):

Where you have a line of three 2s, you can place a mine south of the eastern one. The western 2 needs one more mine, and there are two squares it can be in. Therefore, there's exactly one mine in those two squares. Now, the middle 2 needs two more mines, and has exactly the same two squares as the western one, plus one more square. This last square must therefore be the middle 2's second mine.

Comment: It did work! Thank you. In the place of the three "two"s , I thought there was two solutions, but it was actually only one solution so that the left "two", didn't have three flags.